# Python websocket create connection

Tags: python, ssl, websocket, autobahn

I have this server

https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_tls/server.py

And I want to connect to the server with this code:

```
ws = create_connection("wss://127.0.0.1:9000")
```

What options do I need to add to `create_connection`? Adding `sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE}` does not work:

```
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 400
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes, websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 400

Comment: Which websocket package are you using? If it's [`websocket`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket), that seems seriously out of date. Try [`websockets`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websockets) or [`websocket-client`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client) instead.

Comment: I am using websocket-client, installed with pip install websocket-client on python 3.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import ssl

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect('wss://127.0.0.1:9000',ssl=ssl.SSLContext(protocol=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)) as websocket:
        data = 'hi'
        await websocket.send(data)
        print("> {}".format(data))

        response = await websocket.recv()
        print("< {}".format(response))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

Comment: This just saved me a few days of fighting websockets while connecting to them via proxy. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

For me the option from the question seems to work:

```
from websocket import create_connection
import ssl

ws = create_connection("wss://echo.websocket.org", sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})

ws.send("python hello!")
print (ws.recv())
ws.close()
```

See also here:
https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client#faq

Note: I'm using win7 with python 3.6.5 with following packages installed(pip):

- simple-websocket-server==0.4.0
- websocket-client==0.53.0
- websockets==6.0